# JQuery Access iFrame same domaine

Tags: jquery, iframe

I want access to the content of an iFrame, on the same domain. I have a small and easy example but it doesnt' work, I search the problem since too much time :-(

Here is my code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr" lang="fr">
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){   
            alert($('#iframeID').contents().find('#someID').html());
        });
    </script>
 </head>
<body>  
    <iframe id="iframeID" src="test.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

And the frame called :

```
<div id="someID">Hello world!</div>
```

Can someone help me please ?
Thank you for your help

Mathieu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get `iframe` as

`console.log($('#iframeID', window.parent.document));`

You need to wrap code inside of `window.load` or need to wrap it inside `.load()` because your `iframe` contents are not getting load before code is executing.

```
<script>
    $(window).load(function(){   
        //alert($('#iframeID').contents().find('#someID').html());
        console.log($("#iframeID", window.parent.document).contents().find("div"));
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to make sure the iframe is loaded before searching inside.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#iframeID").load(function(){   
        alert($(this).contents().find('#someID').html());
    });
});
```

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhh :-) :-) That works
Thank you so much for your quick help !